# Closed form of solutions of $xy-zv=±1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let us consider a real dynamical system $s′=h(s)$. In order to study the stability of the central manifold, we reformulate the problem as follows: I am asking if this equation
$$xy-zv=±1$$
has integer solutions $x,y,z,v$.

We can find some special cases, but I am interested in a closed-form.

Comment: $x,y$: any numbers. $z,v$: any divisors of $xy\pm1$. That's about as close to a closed form as it gets.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'd say $zv$ any factorization of $xy\mp1$.

Comment: @Servaes That's right, point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Bezout identity, there are solutions iff $x,z$ are relative primes, and $y,v$ follow.

Comment: Unique modulo something, that is.